# Ruby not picking up .gemrc

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm having trouble running a gem on system ruby -- I've done the install, and the gem runs when rvm runs 1.9.2, but doesn't run on rvm system, though that too is 1.9.2.  The OS is OSX 10.6.8.

One importance difference seems to be GEM_HOME, as seen in rvm info.  This is set for rvm 1.9.2, to values in ~/.gemrc, but not set for rvm system.

So at a guess, the system ruby isn't reading the .gemrc file.

Is there anyway to verify this?
How can I correct it?

The system ruby was installed from source.

The gem in question is compass, version 0.12.1.  An install of 0.11.5 also failed.
Also, gem -v is 1.5.3.  That's a rollback, I was using 1.8.24 but that too failed and I rolled back to a prior to see if that helped.

Comment: try: `rvm mount /path/to/ruby`

Answer (score 0):

The system Ruby doesn't know about any gems you've installed in RVM managed Rubies, nor will it care about a `.gemrc` file.

The system Ruby stands alone, and for most purposes should be left as it was installed by Apple unless you reeeeeeally know why it's there and what it affects. Apple had their own reasons for installing Ruby and at least one app installed by Apple by default on a Mac OS machine requires it. We're free to use it, but deleting it will break that app, and updating it could cause problems that possibly won't surface immediately, so I think it's best to just ignore it.

If I *need* a system-wide Ruby for a Mac, I'd install it from source into `/usr/local/bin`, which is the appropriate place for a replacement. For my own development, I use RVM or rbenv, and let them install in my home directory, which is their default. That way I'm free to mess around to my heart's content, and even blow them away, without any chance of affecting the system.

By the way, the version of Ruby isn't important, it's what installed it and where it's installed.

Comment: I kept /usr/bin/ruby, moving it to /usr/bin/ruby.bak while I experimented.  I've since restored it.  The installations have gone into /usr/local/bin, as you suggest.  

But if system ruby won't run the gems I need, for whatever reason, I don't see how to get Apache to run them in connection with the web applications I'm developing.  Should I be looking at something like Passenger to point Apache at the proper ruby installation and environment?

Comment: Passenger works nicely on Linux, but I haven't tried it on Mac OS. If you're writing using a standard non-Passenger CGI-type of app, your `#!` will define which Ruby to use if I remember right.

Comment: is php/symfony2, served over apache (for development work).  not sure i understand how #! will define the Ruby as its a PHP app, probably because I haven't researched how ruby / compass fits into the Symfony framework

Comment: btw, all this works fine on linux -- but i need it on my laptop so i can work on it away from the office